# JavaScript warning: Assignment to property of function parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I compiled [vue-flash-message](https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message) component from sources and got the following warning:

```
✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign  Assignment to property of function parameter 'Vue'
src\components\vue-flash-message\index.js:173:5
  Vue.prototype[options.storage] = FlashBus;
```

in the following code:

```
export default {
  install(Vue, config = {}) {
    const defaults = {
      method: 'flash',
      storage: '$flashStorage',
      createShortcuts: true,
      name: 'flash-message',
    };
    const options = Object.assign(defaults, config);
    ...
  const FlashBus = new Vue({
    data() {
      return {
        storage: {
        },
      };
    },
    methods: {
      flash(msg, type, opts) {
        return new FlashMessage(FlashBus, msg, type, opts);
      },
      push(id, message) {
        Vue.set(this.storage, id, message);
      },
      destroy(id) {
        Vue.delete(this.storage, id);
      },
      destroyAll() {
        Vue.set(this, 'storage', {});
      },
    },
  });
    ...
    Vue.prototype[options.storage] = FlashBus;

    ...
  },
};
```

is it possible to correct the code and make it compile without warnings?

Comment: I dont see what is FlashBus? Is it Vue's global variable?

Comment: Not too sure how Vue extensions work but this does look like a deliberate attempt to add something to the prototype by the plugin author so you can probably ignore the warning since it's not your own code. Presumably the warning comes from your linter

Comment: What is the goal of the `Vue.prototype[options.storage] = FlashBus;` line? Changing the prototype behind every `Vue` instance -- and in particular with an enumerable property -- seems like a Bad Thing. :-)

Comment: @TimaGegewepe FlashBus is defined above, see https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Just disable the warning if you disagree with it.

Comment: @Bergi it is the only warning in the project, it is better to fix the code.

Comment: @TJCrowder the goal is probably to do something global in the app.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky in github, that piece of code is not in that block.

Comment: @TimaGegewepe see https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky if it's not your code, it's not your code to fix. You should not run your linter on third party code **as they may be coding using completely different coding conventions and rules** you can't just force everyone to code with your standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue.

You have an ES Lint rule setup for `no-param-reassign`. This conflicts with `Vue`'s way of creating plugins, where you are directed to write to the `prototype` directly. [You can see my statement reinforced here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin)

Your only choice is to `fork` that project, and ignore the line with your linter if it's bugging you that much.